# Embed LWC component in visualforce page and load lwc component onclick of a button in classic

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps

I want to call lwc component on click of a button in classic. I created a VF page and trying to embed lwc component. Below is my code

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="compContainer" />
    <script>
     $Lightning.use("c:embedContractrRequestRTApp",function() {
         $Lightning.createComponent("contractRequestRecordTypes",
          {
              recordId : '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}'
          },
          "compContainer",
          function(cmp) {
               console.log("c:VFPageApp loaded successfully in VF page");
           }
         );
     });
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

embedContractrRequestRTApp:

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="global">
    <c:contractRequestRecordTypes></c:contractRequestRecordTypes>/>  
</aura:application>
```

When I try to preview this VF page or call on click of button from the account it gives error - **Lightning out App error in callback function**  How this can be fixed? Is there any alternate way we can call lwc component on click of a button from salesforce classic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.lightning_out_dependencies) you need to specify the component as a dependency:

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="global">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:contractRequestRecordTypes"/>
</aura:application>
```

Also your code should be:

```javascript
$Lightning.use('c:embedContractrRequestRTApp', function() {
    $Lightning.createComponent(
        'c:contractRequestRecordTypes',
        {
            recordId: "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"
        },
        'compContainer',
        function(cmp) {
            console.log('component created {!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}');
    });
});
```

Comment: I still get this error - Lightning out App error in callback function

Comment: Look at the updated response.